# How to write routing prefixes dynamically from DB

Tags: cakephp, configuration, prefix

i have db table with the prefixes and need them to be readable in app_controller beforeFilter  
`$prefix_array = array('admin', 'marketing');

if ($this->Auth->user() AND in_array(@$this->params['prefix'], $prefix_array)) { $this->layout  = 'admin'; } else { $this->layout  = 'default';}`

-where should i do it in bootstrap or app_controller?
-how can i dynamically read prefix from DB, set to $prefix_array
-write them to Configure::write('Routing.prefixes')

Comment: I've answered below, but I'm not sure about the logic behind your requirement to automatically map prefixes to routes, as code changes would be required. You would need to add/remove controller actions.  Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

In your app controller, just load the prefixes:

```
var $uses = array('Prefix');

function beforeFilter() {
    $prefixes = $this->Prefix->find('list');
    if($this->Auth->user() && in_array($this->params['prefix'], $prefixes) {
        $this->layout = 'admin';
    }
}
```

Comment: but how about to Configure::write('Routing.prefixes'). where should i write the values to Configure::write('Routing.prefixes') in bootstrap or app_controller?

Comment: I commented on your question, asking why you want to do this.  I don't see the benefit to setting prefixes dynamically when they're linked to actions (code).  Can you elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: because i have actions in product controller ex. (admin_edit, marketing_edit, warehouse_edit) and all of the should be defined in Configure::write('Routing.prefixes'). i can do it manually but how to do it dynamically.

Comment: There's no point in doing it dynamically.  How often are you going be adding/removing prefixes? You're going to write 30 lines of code to save you 5.